# VB.net write dataset to non-consecutive columns in XLSX

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, xlsx

I have a little issue regarding writing queried data to an xlsx file but not in consecutive columns

The code below is a snippet regarding my current method of writing the four columns of a query to a spreadsheet starting at C6, so the data is in C, D, E and F.

My interest now is to write the same dataset to columns C, E, H, and L. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Richard

```
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(Query1, SQLConn)

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i, j As Integer
    da.Fill(ds)

    'Write to Excel
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            xlSht.Cells(i + 6, j + 3) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j).ToString
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an array of column indexes like this:

```
Dim colIndexes As Integer() = {2, 4, 7, 11} '{C, E, H, L}
```

Then replace `j+3` with `colIndexes(j)`to write into the correct cell

```
xlSht.Cells(i + 6, colIndexes(j)) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j).ToString
```

Comment: Beautiful. Works a dream. Thanks for the ridiculously quick reply. All is well with the world again, and I've learned something. Richard